# When rounding integer, don't add to the end

Tags: python, integer, decimal, rounding

I currently am trying to work with a number that has variable decimal place lengths. It can either be an integer, or have up to 10 decimals i.e. 33.3333333. I wanted to restrict the number to only have 2 decimals when it exceeds the length, or maintain the original if it's less.

I've tried using `"{:0:.2f}".format`, but the problem is that for integers, it also adds .00 to the end of the string.

When I tried using `round(3)` it'll return 3.0.

Is there a method, preferably a single line, that can convert 3.333333 to 3.33 but still allow for 3 to stay as an int?

Comment: Are you using Python 2? Because `round(3)` returns `3`, not `3.0`, in Python 3. You should probably upgrade (Python 2 hit end of life a year and a half ago).

Answer (score 1):

Try choosing the format as a function of the values wholeness:

```
"{d}" if int(a) == a else "{:0:.2f}"
```

Can you finish from there?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) to choose the format based on the type of the variable:

```
for x in (33.3333333, 3):
    print(("{:0}" if isinstance(x, int) else "{:.2f}").format(x))
```

You could also implement it using a dictionary to map types to format strings:

```
formats = {int: "{:0}", float: "{:.2f}"}

for x in (33.3333333, 3):
    print(formats.get(type(x)).format(x))
```